# IPython/Jupyter Notebook: How to render a markdown cell without reloading doc?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

In IPython/Jupyter notebooks, is there a clear, concise summary of the 'rules' for when markdown is rendered into that nice, rich text format that's pleasant to look at?

Here's what I've got so far:

1. When I create a new cell, then switch it to 'Markdown' it stays in 'raw markdown mode' (meaning: I can see the raw markdown.  There's some nice, syntax-based color-coding and font-sizing, but it's clearly raw markdown)
2. If I save the notebook, close it (i.e., close the browser's page) and then re-open the notebook I see the nice, rich-text version of the markdown (i.e., "#Topic 1" is rendered as H1 by the browser, and the browser hides the "#" at the start - it's clearly NOT the 'raw markdown'
3. If I click on the markdown cell it remains in 'nice mode'
4. If I press the 'Enter' key I enter Jupyter's edit mode, it replaces the 'nice mode' view with the 'raw markdown mode' view, and I can edit the markdown.

What I'd love to know is:
**How do I get Jupyter to render that 'raw markdown mode' cell again?** (Without closing and re-opening the notebook)

(Alternately -is this the expected behavior?  You get the nice view when you first load it, and you're stuck with the 'raw markdown' view for any cell you edit until you reload it?)

Comment: Shift+enter goes from raw mode to nice mode, just like executing a code cell.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You just need to *execute or run the cell* which is in markdown format.

If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> will execute and convert the raw text to markdown form.

Or you can press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> which will execute the current cell and will move to the next one.

Comment: LOL!  Well, that was easy. :)
Thank you very much for answering my beginner question!

Comment: I wish `run all cells` would render the markdown cells as well. Coming from a traditional programming background initially it's a bit unintuitive to believe that we can execute the markdown cells as well.

Comment: simple but very unintuitive for me to search for this on SO!